GitHubActions Workflow not pushing zipped file to UCD
I am developing a pipeline to upload build to UCD. The problem is my build bundle a zip file won;t be pushed there. If I omit the base include and exclude for the add VersionsFile command. Everything is uploaded except my zip.
I have the following in my workflow:
 include_files: |
    *.zip
 exclude_files: |
    */**/*

